# Return distinct ID based on few criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to return the `DISTINCT` IDs from a table if it meets certain criteria.

> 1. An ID must contain CID of 1,26,33,49 (all)
> 2. An ID should NOT contain CID of 38 or 46 or 67

Here's the table.

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c1.id) FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2
ON c1.id = c2.ID
AND c2.CID = 38
where c2.id IS null
```

This only works if I specify a single ID that should not be presented. If I replace this

```
AND c2.CID = 38
```

with

```
AND c2.CID IN (38,46,67)
```

This will not return me the correct ID. Also, if I add a criteria for `c1.CID` to include IDs `1,26,33,49` It will also return an incorrect ID.

Based on this example table, I should only get back ID `12345`.

Here's [SQLFIDDLE.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c862/3)

I'm trying to get this output without using a `subquery`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand why this query doesn't work: "select distinct ID from yourTable where CID in (1,26,33,49)"

Comment: That will not work. An `ID` can have multiple rows with different `CIDs`. If I just do a single select, then it will only exclude the row, but it will not exclude the ID.

Comment: @burzum 'criteria' IS plural, the singular is 'criterion', thus 'criterias' is not a word.

Comment: @RicardoC, thanks. Did not know that.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a subquery? or are you just like i was when I first started learning SQL where I was just scared of them because I did not understand them?

Comment: I'm just trying to stay away from them in general if I can avoid them ;)

Comment: How do you feel about a temp table?

Comment: Prefer `CTE` over temp table. But I do use them. Will the last question be about `triggers`?

Comment: No just thought I had an idea that would work using a temp table testing it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c862/9)

Use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT id
FROM cte
group by id
having sum(case when cid in (1,26,33,49) then 1 else 0 end) = 4
and sum(case when cid in (38,46,67) then -1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works for me. Could you explain what `sum` is doing here. I understand the case and `4` is representing all IDs must be present, but I don't understand the purpose of `sum`.

Comment: you assign 1 to rows containing those values and sum them for each id and check if it is 4. for the cid's that should be excluded you do the same but assign -1 to rows that have those 3 cid's and then do a sum. If any of these cid's is present for a given id then the sum would not be 0 and the condition fails and those id's won't be returned.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a working query, but looks very strange :)

```
-- An ID must contain CID of 1,26,33,49 (all)
-- An ID should NOT contain CID of 38 or 46 or 67
SELECT valid.ID
FROM (
  SELECT ID, CID 
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE CID IN (1,26,33,49)
  GROUP BY ID, CID
) AS valid
WHERE valid.ID NOT IN (
  SELECT ID FROM CTE WHERE CID IN (38,46,67) GROUP BY ID, CID
)
GROUP BY valid.ID
HAVING COUNT(valid.CID) = 4
```

Working sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c862/41

P.S. '4' is the number of mandatory IDs. if you change the number of parameters - HAVING COUNT clause should be updated accordingly.

Comment: @pavel_morshenyuk I suggest to edit as: HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT valid.CID) = 4  You need to account for possible multiple entries for a given CID.

Comment: @ricardo-c thanks for the suggestion! Probably it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

EXCEPT is opposite to UNION in a manner of speaking.

```
SELECT c1.id
FROM    cte c1 
WHERE c1.CID IN(1,26,33,49)
GROUP BY c1.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c1.CID) = 4

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT c1.id
FROM    cte c1 
WHERE c1.CID IN(38,46,67)
```

Comment: Other examples do not account for duplicate entries e.g. four duplicated records with ID 12345 and CID 26

Comment: Strange. It works in SQLFIDDLE, but when I run the same query against my table, I get no results back.

Comment: @burzum umm maybe your table is different, try copying from sqlfiddle both parts; the 'build schema' and 'run sql' and test that in your SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a temp table this works. And here is the SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c862/39/0

```
Select
  C.ID
 ,C.CID
 ,Case C.CID
   When 1  then 'Y'
   When 26 then 'Y'
   When 33 then 'Y'
   When 49 then 'Y'
   Else 'N'
  End as "Keep"
 ,Case C.CID
   When 38 then 'Y'
   When 46 then 'Y'
   When 67 then 'Y'
   Else 'N'
  End as "Remove"

 Into #Temp

 From CTE as C



 Select Distinct
   T.ID

 From #Temp as T

Group by T.ID

Having
  Sum(Case When T.Keep = 'Y' Then 1 Else 0 End) = 4
  and
  Sum(Case When T.Remove = 'Y' then 1 Else 0 End) = 0
```

At first I did not take into account if the same idea had multiple of the same CID was even an option. If this is you should be able to add a distinct to the first select statement to make this still work.

Comment: Plus `1` for the effort!

Comment: dang same concept but without the temp table @vkp did good there I did not think of using the having clause till after i got the temp table. close though

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you do something like this?

```
  AND c2.CID = 38 OR c2.CID = 46 OR c2.CID = 67
```

or

```
 AND c2.CID Like (38,46,67)
```